# Object lifetime in static list - weak reference of objects

Tags: c#

At the moment I have the following class.

```
class BaseClass : IDisposable
{
    private static List<BaseClass> instances = new List<BaseClass>();

    protected BaseClass()
    {
        instances.Add(this);
    }
    ~BaseClass()
    {
        Dispose();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        instances.Remove(this);
    }
}
```

So the lifetime of every class that inherit the `BaseClass` is infinitely until I close the program or I will call Dispose explicity.

Can I prevent this behaviour, so that lifetime is back to normal? (of course without removing the possibility to access the derived objects, otherwise my question make no sense)

I add the static List, to handle various actions to all classes that inherit `BaseClass`.

---

### Edit

```
class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
}


//This case works
using (DerivedClass _dc = new DerivedClass())
{
      //Do something with object
}
//This object will live forever, because it is internally in the static list
//That behaviour is not desired
DerivedClass dc = new DerivedClass();
```

How I can get the bahaviour that `DerivedClass dc` calls his destructor after the normal lifetime (as it would not be in the list)?

---

### Background

I want to fill the Properties of the derived classes with values from a config file and do it in base class. But if the config file changed, I have to change all properties of alll derived classes. So if you know a way to get all objects that implements the base class and needs to be changed, let me know it.

---

## Update

### Solution 1: Based on my question

With help from [Steve Mitcham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10156/steve-mitcham) ([Go to post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27977961/object-lifetime-in-static-list-weak-reference-of-objects#27978306)) I found out how I can make a weak reference with few lines of code:

```
class BaseClass : IDisposable
{
    private static List<GCHandle> handles = new List<GCHandle>();
    protected BaseClass()
    {
        this.handle = GCHandle.Alloc(this, GCHandleType.Weak);
        handles.Add(this.handle);
    }
    ~BaseClass()
    {
        Dispose();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (handle.IsAllocated)
        {
            //Do Something more to Dispose the Object
            //...
            handle.Free();
            handles.Remove(handle);
        }
    }
    public void DoSomethingWithTheList()
    {
        foreach (GCHandle handle in handles)
        {
            BaseClass bc = (BaseClass)handle.Target;
            //Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Now If I call `GC.Collect();` it will collect my unused derived classes (so I think the garbage collector will collect my objects normally as well) because the object itself has no reference in a list.

Thank you!

### Solution 2: Subsrciber / Broadcaster Pattern

With this pattern it is simple too. Additionally the derived class can get the info if the values are changed.
Thank you [Alireza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815231/alireza) ([Goto post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27977961/object-lifetime-in-static-list-weak-reference-of-objects#27979167)) and [Thangadurai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1363011/thangadurai).

```
class ConfigurationBroadcaster
{
    string path = "";
    public string Path
    {
        get { return path; }
        set 
        {
            bool changed = path != value;
            path = value;
            if(changed)
            if (ChangedConfigurationValues != null)
            {
                Delegate[] invocationList = ChangedConfigurationValues.GetInvocationList();
                foreach (var item in invocationList)
                {
                    Type t = item.Target.GetType();
                    PropertyInfo[] pInfos = t.GetProperties();
                    foreach (PropertyInfo pInfo in pInfos)
                    {
                        //new object() have to be the value from config file
                        //5 is used to set Width and Height from BroadcastSubscriber for this example
                        pInfo.SetValue(item.Target, 5/* new object()*/, null);
                    }
                }
               ChangedConfigurationValues(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }
    }
    public event EventHandler ChangedConfigurationValues;
}
class BaseBroadcastSubscriber
{
    ConfigurationBroadcaster broadcaster;
    protected BaseBroadcastSubscriber(ConfigurationBroadcaster broadcaster)
    {
        this.broadcaster = broadcaster;
        this.broadcaster.ChangedConfigurationValues += new EventHandler(broadcaster_ChangedConfigurationValues);
    }

    void broadcaster_ChangedConfigurationValues(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Configuration values changed");
    }
}
class BroadcastSubscriber : BaseBroadcastSubscriber
{
    int width,height;

    public int Width
    {
        get { return width; }
        set { width = value; }
    }

    public int Height
    {
        get { return height; }
        set { height = value; }
    }
    public BroadcastSubscriber(ConfigurationBroadcaster broadcaster)
        : base(broadcaster)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you be manually holding onto the instances of the objects you are creating?

Comment: Please read the last sentence. I have to handle various actions to all objects. If you know another way to do it, feel free to explain it.

Comment: set `instances = null` whenever you dont want to persisr this static List in memory...

Comment: In what instance do you not want one of these instances to live forever? Is it an all or nothing thing, or just particular items?

Comment: I want back to the normal behaviour of objects (as the objects are not in the list). So no instance should live forever.

Comment: Just drop the list and your Dispose implementation,  you don't need it under normal circumstances.  Can you add an example of an operation you are using the list for?

Comment: If you don't want the objects to be kept in a list any more, then don't put them in the list. (And if you want to forget the objects that are already in the list, then empty the list.)

Comment: I want to fill the Properties of the derived classes with values from a config file and do it in base class. But if the config file changed, I have to change all properties of alll derived classes. So if you know a way to get all objects that implements the base class and needs to be changed, let me know it.

Comment: @MitjaS. Excuse me for the theoretical info.  Your requirement looks like a publisher/subscriber pattern. You can have a separate object to hold your configurations and let all your subclasses subscribe to it for any changes.

Comment: With your alternate solution, the derived classes will only get cleaned up if explicitly disposed (which isn't necessarily wrong, just a caveat on usage).

Comment: Steve's last comment should be considered with high value. Using WeakReference rather than normal Event has benefits such as not preventing object being garbage collected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing more of your program it would be difficult to determine whether your approach could be improved.  However, without fundamentally changing your design I would use WeakReferences to track your objects. The UpdateClasses method is to simulate your reconfigure action.

```
class BaseClass : IDisposable
{
    private WeakReference<BaseClass> myReference;
    private static List<WeakReference<BaseClass>> instances = new List<WeakReference>();

    public static UpdateClasses(MyData stuff)
    {
        foreach(var ref in instances)
        {
           BaseClass target;
           if (ref.TryGetTarget(out target))
           {
               // code to update target here
           }
        }
    }
    protected BaseClass()
    {
       myReference = new WeakReference<BaseClass>(this,true);
       instances.Add(myReference);
    }

    ~BaseClass()
    {
       Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
       instances.Remove(myReference);
    }
}
```

The weak references will not keep your objects alive.  When they get garbage collected they will remove their references from the instance list.  Note, however, that this implementation will cause your objects to stay alive in the garbage collector longer than normal due to the requirement for the finalizer, and this may decrease the performance of the application over time.

Comment: WeakReference I could find here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/68990/Creating-a-Weak-List has many classes. But it is what I searched. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Despite Steve Mitchman's answer, you could design a broadcaster class providing an event which gets fired whenever a change in config file is detected. Derived classes (objects) could subscribe to this event and unsubscribe upon being get GC collected or finalized. This approach follows open/closed principle very well.

Comment: I will add an example to my question. Not that difficult like I thought. Thank you.

Comment: Having the classes subscribe to the event will cause a reference that will prevent them from being garbage collected, so you will have to build the weak references into the broadcaster class or enforce disposal through the usage of the dervied classes.  Also, I was trying not to change the design, but I would agree that a different design is probably a better solution

Comment: @SteveMitcham You are completely right and I missed the point. However, I think subscriber/broadcaster pattern (implemented using WeakReference than event) is still defensible.

Comment: We are in agreement about your implementation being quite viable.

Answer (score 0):

When your BaseClass instance is off, that is both when you call the Dispose and when the instance itself is destroyed. These cases are normal.

Comment: I know about normal cases. I need a tweak to get access to all derived objects without changing their lifetime.